# GeoTIFF retiling

Tags: gdal, tiles, gdal-translate

I have a set of worldcover 3x3 degree GeoTIFFs and I am trying to break them down into 1x1 degree files to match the DEM files I have. The 3deg tiles have 36000 rows and 36000 cols. I used gdal_translate with this command to make a single 1x1 tile at a time from a 3 degree tile. It "should" take the bottom left 1 degree by 1 degree portion and create a new file named for the top left corner instead of the bottom left so it matches my dem file naming convention.

```
gdal_translate -projwin -96.000 31.00 -95.000 30.000 /mnt/volume_nyc1_01/Landcover/10m/N30W096_Map.tif /mnt/volume_nyc1_01/Landcover/10m/N31W096.tif
```

If I look at the image it created with a TIFF viewer, it looks just like the 1 degree portion of the 3 degree tile and has 12000 rows and 12000 cols. However, the 1x1 DEMS are 10812x10812 and both are supposedly 1/3 arc second resolution.

The pixel size in the worldcover file is 0.000083333333333 which is really 0.3 degrees (should be 0.333333 based on the stated 1/3 arc sec resolution). My DEM files are more correct with a pixel size of 0.000092592592526.

```
The orginal file has these specs:
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: /mnt/volume_nyc1_01/Landcover/10m/N30W096_Map.tif
Size is 36000, 36000
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-96.000000000000000,33.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.000083333333333,-0.000083333333333)
```

and the translated file has this:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: /mnt/volume_nyc1_01/Landcover/10m/N31W096c.tif
Size is 12000, 12000
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-96.000000000000000,31.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.000083333333333,-0.000083333333333)
```

The file size also increased dramatically with all the new 1x1 files having the exact same size or 140,699KB. This particular 3x3 file was 80,736KB at 3x3. I'm struggling to figure out what is actually happening here. Why, if the files are supposed to be the same resolution, do they have different pixel sizes? The files are different datums (DEM is Nad83 and Worldcover is WGS84, but I can't imagine that would make any difference.

I also tried using gdal_retile, but I still had to set the pixel size there to 12000 x 12000 to get 1x1 degree tiles. The file size came out the same, so there wasn't any difference there. I'm wondering how I can create the tiles to match the grid size of the DEM so I can use the same index for lookups.

For reference, here is the info from the DEM:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: /mnt/volume_nyc1_01/SRTM/10m/N31W096.tif
Size is 10812, 10812
Coordinate System is:
BOUNDCRS[
    SOURCECRS[
        GEOGCRS["NAD83",
            DATUM["North American Datum 1983",
                ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101004,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
            PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            CS[ellipsoidal,2],
                AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
                    ORDER[1],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
                    ORDER[2],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            ID["EPSG",4269]]],
    TARGETCRS[
        GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
            DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
                ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
            PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            CS[ellipsoidal,2],
                AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
                    ORDER[1],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
                    ORDER[2],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            USAGE[
                SCOPE["unknown"],
                AREA["World"],
                BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],
            ID["EPSG",4326]]],
    ABRIDGEDTRANSFORMATION["Transformation to WGS84",
        METHOD["Position Vector transformation (geog2D domain)",
            ID["EPSG",9606]],
        PARAMETER["X-axis translation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8605]],
        PARAMETER["Y-axis translation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8606]],
        PARAMETER["Z-axis translation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8607]],
        PARAMETER["X-axis rotation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8608]],
        PARAMETER["Y-axis rotation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8609]],
        PARAMETER["Z-axis rotation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8610]],
        PARAMETER["Scale difference",1,
            ID["EPSG",8611]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-96.000555555555152,31.000555555555156)
Pixel Size = (0.000092592592526,-0.000092592592526)
```

Metadata:

```
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  BandDefinitionKeyword=NONE
  DataType=Elevation
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -96.0005556,  31.0005556) ( 96d 0' 2.00"W, 31d 0' 2.00"N)
Lower Left  ( -96.0005556,  29.9994444) ( 96d 0' 2.00"W, 29d59'58.00"N)
Upper Right ( -94.9994444,  31.0005556) ( 94d59'58.00"W, 31d 0' 2.00"N)
Lower Right ( -94.9994444,  29.9994444) ( 94d59'58.00"W, 29d59'58.00"N)
Center      ( -95.5000000,  30.5000000) ( 95d30' 0.00"W, 30d30' 0.00"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  Description = Layer_1
  Min=6.975 Max=153.774
  Minimum=6.975, Maximum=153.774, Mean=69.672, StdDev=26.084
  NoData Value=-999999
  Overviews: 5406x5406, 2703x2703, 1352x1352, 676x676, 338x338
  Metadata:
    LAYER_TYPE=athematic
    RepresentationType=ATHEMATIC
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=153.77395629883
    STATISTICS_MEAN=69.671522333585
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=6.9750690460205
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=26.08433543729
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Looks like you are confusing degrees with arc seconds (1 degree is 60 arc minutes, 1 arc minute is 60 arc seconds). File size changes will heavily depend on what compression you are using - all the files being the same size suggests no compression. Also, it looks like the DEM has an extra row and column on the boundary (i.e. the tiles overlap, instead of being adjacent), which is pretty common (e.g. DTED format does this).

Comment: How am I confusing degrees with arc seconds? The files are 3x3 degree tiles (worldcover), and 1x1 degree tiles (DEM) from the source with a resolution of 1/3 arc second (roughly 10m). I'm not sure there is any confusion there. Is there a compression option in either the gdal_translate, or gdal_retile.py commands? Maybe I missed it.

Comment: The pixel size description of `0.000083333333333 which is really 0.3 degrees (should be 0.333333 based on the stated 1/3 arc sec resolution` is what led me to suggest you might be confusing size.

Comment: The compression options are described at https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html#creation-options - for example `COMPRESS=LZW`. Some compression types have sub-options (like `ZLEVEL=3`).

Comment: Well further research into the formats indicates that the worldcover files are indeed 10m and not 3 arc second. This is surprising as the distance is not consistent in all lat/lons and you would think GIS people would want to deal in something consistent.  I'm assuming they mean 10m at the equator which would yield roughly 11,113 points over 1 degree. Assuming there is overlap it may get us to 12000. Looks like I'll just have to deal with 2 different resolutions.

Comment: It might be, but it might not. There are multiple ways to do tiling / gridding, and some of them work area as the consistent factor, some work distance in degrees, some work distance in metres. Can you have another pass over the question to see if you can turn it into a single issue (i.e. just one question mark) that expresses what you actually need to know?